# Qt5 Applications crashing at startup

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

I have installed Qt 5.0.1 - 32-bit Version on Ubuntu 12.04. All the programs crash at startup with the following messages :

> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>
> /home/manager/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc/examples/opengl/2dpainting-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/2dpainting
> exited with code 0

I tried:

1. Making the default Qml Application
2. Running a few example applications.

I switched between the debug and release modes as well, but all crashed with similar message. Surprisingly 'Animated Tiles example' works fine. Any suggestions ?

---

Edit:

In debug mode this is what i get:

> Debugging starts
>
> &"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"
>
> RTTI symbol not found for class 'QGLWidget'
>
> RTTI symbol not found for class 'QGLWidget'
>
> RTTI symbol not found for class 'QGLWidget'
>
> RTTI symbol not found for class 'QGLWidget'

Comment: You should run the debug build with a debugger and get the stack trace when the application crashes

Comment: @Andreas Added the same in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on Windows with Qt5. As i understood, in qt5 window subsystem moved into plugins and when application start, QApplication object can't find this libraries.

On windows I step-trace my app into Qt code, and find that plugins try to load from folder ./plugins/system where . is folder with our app binary. Also it was a problem with 
dependence. Windows specific plugin dependence from libGLES.dll or libGLES2.dll. But GL libs must place in the same folder as app binary, not with plugins.

Correct file tree on Windows look like this

```
plugins
 system
   platform.dll
   windows.dll
libGLES.dll
MyApp.exe
```

Try to look in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your graphics driver is installed. 
Qt5 or higher version supports OpenGL 3.0 or higher, if your system is old one, i think you need to check the graphics card can support OPENGL verion as i mentioned above.

If above things are fine, then i think you need to install some opengl libraries that can be easily downloadable from Ubuntu.

Regards
Ansif